# Confused with this application of induction

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation, solution-verification

I am reading through *Computational Geometry in C, 2nd Edition*. In the book there is a proof for the existence of a triangulation that goes as follows:

> If $n = 3$ the polygon is a triangle, and the theorem holds trivially.
>   Let $n \ge 4$. Let $d = ab$ be a diagonal of $P$ as guaranteed by
>   lemma 1.2.2. Because $d$ by definition only intersects $\partial{P}$
>   at its endpoints, it partitions P into two polygons each using $d$ as
>   an edge, and each of fewer than $n$ vertices. The reason each has
>   fewer vertices is that no vertices are added by this process, and
>   clearly there is at least one vertex in each part in addition to $a$
>   and $b$. **Applying the induction hypothesis completes this proof**.

The bold portion is what has confused me. I am very familiar with induction - however when I have used induction it is always "explicit". For example, mentioning "now assume this holds for n, let's look at what happens to n+1" or something.

When the author states "apply the induction hypothesis" this, in my mind, is equivalent to "assume this holds for all $n$". I feel like it would be necessary for the author to prove the $n-1$th case here for the proof to be complete - however admittedly the author knows more about proofs than I do!

Can someone explain how this is a valid application of induction? I'd like to add it to my proof toolbox because it is very succinct and clear.

Comment: Each of the two regions has fewer vertices than the original so the induction is on the number of vertices.  Inductively, we know we can triangulate each of the smaller regions and the union of the two triangulations is a triangulation of the entire polygon.

Comment: This is an example of complete induction.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Complete_(strong)_induction